# Trying to get Nvidia drivers to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a laptop with an Intel processor and integrated graphics (I7), with an Nvidia GeForce gtx 1060. I have windows and Ubuntu 19.04 installed.

I tried installing the Nvidia drivers (418) from the PPA and after disabling secure boot, the drivers seem to work, but I only get output on my second display (connected to HDMI), and the main laptop screen is black. Additionally, if I disconnect the HDMI cable, I still get no output on the laptop display.

I tried uninstalling the Nvidia drivers and go back to the default display drivers, but I still get issues with my dual monitor setup, where I get weird glitches on my second display, or no output at all

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? When I had the Nvidia drivers, I could only see the second display in the Nvidia settings and ubuntu settings.

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"` 3. `sudo lshw -c video`  4. `dkms status` 5. `lsmod | grep nvidia` 6. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and 7 `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"`

Comment: Right now I am running the default display driver (`xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`), I can reinstall the Nvidia drivers but that will probably mess up my display again.

Comment: So, you are happy with `nouveau` driver, @Ido Bronfeld. Then there is no issue at all!

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post ate least the results from the first command in the first comment (or if you know already tell us, have you installed in UEFI mode or Legacy?)